# How can I convert a string to a BigInt in an action parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which I want to display, for which I have a controller which accepts a string (StudentID). Here is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult ShowStudent(string StudentID)
{
    ViewData.Model = student.vwStudent.Where(s => s.StudentID == StudentID);
    return View();
}
```

Now here, StudentId's have leading zeros in them. e.g. 00003345, 000000223 etc.
Hence, to display the view for a particular student, I have to enter the exact string "00003345" in the url: "http://Students/ShowStudent/00003345" I want to be able to display the view even if I enter "3345" in the url: "http://Students/ShowStudent/3345" but I get an error.

I have tried passing a Long(Int64) parameter instead of a string and converting StudentID to String in ViewData.Model like:

```
ViewData.Model = student.vwStudent.Where(s => s.StudentID == StudentID.ToString());
```

But I get an error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

EDIT:
What is wrong with just parsing it to an Int64 like this:

```
ViewData.Model = student.vwStudent.Where(s => Int64.Parse(s.StudentID) == Int64.Parse(StudentID));
```

Comment: if a value is string there's no need to call `ToString()` again. But you mentioned you got an error when you tried to use that resource without the leading zeroes.. what kind of error was it? I think you shouldn't use `Long` there.. maybe it's a matter of formatting the parameter adding the zeroes.. can you show the error you got when you tried that?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Sorry, I dont get an error when I enter student id without the leading zeros, It does not show any results. I have to enter it exactly "00003345"

Comment: So why don't you try adding the missing zeroes on your action? (in the action but **before** you pass the parameter to the query) Or maybe add the zeros when you render the view (on the get action)?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Also, I am calling ToString() when I change StudentID parameter to "Int64" instead of "string". After changing the parameter type to "Int64", if I dont call ToString() it gives and error: Delegate 'System.Func<Stu.Models.vwStudent,int,bool>' does not take one argument on: s => s.StudentID == StudentID);

Comment: There you go.. people are answering what I told you :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help, I took a bit of all of your advices and came to a solution that works for me.

I Was able to resolve this by Casting in my SQL:

```
CAST(CAST(StudentID AS bigint) AS nvarchar(33)) AS StudentID
```

And then converting it in my Controller:

```
var StudentID = Convert.ToString(Int64.Parse(StudentId));

ViewData.Model = student.vwStudent.Where(a => a.StudentID == StudentId);
```

Answer (score 4):

Does the following work?

```
public ActionResult ShowStudent(string StudentID)
{
    var padded = StudentID.PadLeft(8, '0');
    ViewData.Model = student.vwStudent.Where(s => s.StudentID == padded);
    return View();
}
```

Alternatively, if StudentID is not always added to 8 characters, you may have to query for all possible StudentID's with the underlying SQL LIKE operator:

```
var students = student.vwStudent.Where(s => s.StudentID.EndsWith(StudentID));
```

Then loop through these results looking for the right match.

Finally, if you prefer to just send all possible matches to the query for an exact return using the underlying SQL IN operator:

```
public ActionResult ShowStudent(string StudentID)
{
    var possibleStudents = Enumerable.Range(StudentID.Length, 8 - StudentID.Length).Select(l => StudentID.PadLeft(l, '0'));
    ViewData.Model = student.vwStudent.Where(s => possibleStudents.Contains(s.StudentID));
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @Yamen Is there a way to address numbers stored with no leading zeros in the same column? How should I approach displaying numbers which are not padded with leading zeros?

Comment: Yes, in the underlying SQL you'll want the eventual query to look for `StudentId LIKE '%9999'` so in LINQ `.Where(s => s.StudentId.EndsWith(StudentID)`. But of course you can then get multiple results, for which you'll need to search for the exact match.

Comment: @yamen yes, EndsWith will work but not always, need to find a solution to display output only the student that was entered

Comment: OK added one final option that builds all possible Student ID combinations and checks for exact matches on all of them using Contains (SQL IN operator).

Comment: @yamen your query will still display all possible students. For eg: if a students id is 0022323 and 2323, it will display both

Comment: @user793468 I added a new query, can you try the bottom one? Please read carefully when asking a question and people go to some effort.

Comment: @yamen Thanks for all the help. I was able to get it to work by tweaking my view and controller action.

Answer (score 2):

If your database holds a big int, and you are sending it something smaller....you are getting a `stack overflow`. You need to parse that string into something useful:

```
ViewData.Model = student.vwStudent.Where(s => s.StudentID == long.Parse(StudentID));
```

However, this seems not to be the issue (even though the question clearly states "How to convert a string to a big int").

From your description (`StudentId's have leading zeros in them`) and your comment `I have to enter it exactly "00003345"` I am going to assume that this method needs some *logic*. On the other hard, I am not too sure because your question states that StudentIds are different lengths. ?!

```
public ActionResult ShowStudent(string StudentID)
{
 while( StudentID.Length < 8 )
 {
  StudentID = "0" + StudentID;
 }
 ViewData.Model = student.vwStudent.Where(s => s.StudentID == StudentID);
 return View();
}
```

Or even more fun:

```
public ActionResult ShowStudent(string StudentID)
{
 var x = student.vwStudent.Where(s => s.StudentID == StudentID).FirstOrDefault();
 while( x != null && StudentID.Length < 15)
 {
  StudentID = "0" + StudentID;
  x = student.vwStudent.Where(s => s.StudentID == StudentID).FirstOrDefault();
 }
 ViewData.Model = x;
 return View();
}
```

Or slightly DRYer:

```
public ActionResult ShowStudent(string StudentID)
{
    Student s;
    while( (s=students.FirstOrDefault( x => x.StudentId == StudentId )) == null ) {
        StudentId = "0" + StudentId;
        if( StudentId.Length > 15 ) break;
    }

    return View( s );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ needs to be able to translate all functions to the underlying data store, which is probably why you're getting that error message.  However, if I understand your problem correctly, you should be able to accomplish what you're looking for with the following:

```
public ActionResult ShowStudent(long studentId)
{
    var studentIdStr = studentId.ToString( "D9" );  // 9-digit number, padded w/ zeros
    ViewData.Model = student.vwStudent.Where(s => s.StudentId == studentIdStr);
    return View();
}
```

By the way, the standard way of passing the model to the view is not by setting `ViewData.Model`, but passing it to the `View` method:

```
public ActionResult ShowStudent(long studentId)
{
    var studentIdStr = studentId.ToString( "D9" );  // 9-digit number, padded w/ zeros
    return View( student.vwStudent.Where(s => s.StudentID == studentIdStr) );
}
```

Comment: StudentId is not of fixed length of 9

Comment: My understanding from your question is that it's being stored as a fixed-length string with leading zeros.  You can replace 9 with however long your fixed length is.

Comment: @EthanBrown It is of varying length. Should I rather approach it by making StudentId column of fixed length?

Comment: I think that would be wise...if you're doing string equality, 003 is different from 03 is different from 3, so unless the underlying store is able to convert it to a numeric form before doing the comparison, I think you're best off using a fixed width.  Even better would be storing the student ID as a number, not a string.

Comment: @EthanBrown Changing data types in tables is not in my authority, However I will try talking to the database people here. I highly doubt they will make any data type changes. Hence, want an alternate solution which I am in control of.

Comment: @user793468 - see the bottom of my answer for a workaround without editing your database

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. If the StudendIDs are stored with the leading zeros, then any built-in MVC functions are going to construct the URLs with the same values (meaning **with** the leading zeros). But you can change the Controller method to take a string, then convert it to an Int64, then add the zeros yourself with `.PadLeft()` and the model binding should still work.

```
public ActionResult ShowStudent(string StudentID) 
{ 
    string paddedStudentID = Convert.ToInt64(StudentID).ToString().PadLeft(9, '0');
    ViewData.Model = student.vwStudent.Where(s => s.StudentID == paddedStudentID); 
    return View(); 
}
```

I'm not sure this adds much value, though.

Comment: Is there a way to address numbers stored with no leading zeros in the same column? This column has student id's with leading zeros and some without leading zeros. Hence, I was looking to convert the string to a bigint, which would resolve all the issues, but after trying several ways, I still couldnt convert string to bigint. How should I approach displaying numbers which are not padded with leading zeros?

Comment: I have seen similar situations. The only solution is to convert the resulting column value to a bigint every time you query the database. It can be particularly troublesome if the column is used as a foreign key. Ultimately, it would be in your long term interest to pick either padding or convert the column to bigint, with my preference being the bigint (you can always add the padding for display).

Comment: I guess I didn't really answer your question, what you are after is a way to query where all the possible padding combinations are returned?

Comment: yes, I want to return all padding combinations, even the ones which are not padded.